# Telegram check if user is admin

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using the telegram bot api to make a bot. I have some commands that can only be sent from admins. Like kick and ban commands. How do I check if the sender is an admin or not? I am using the `python-telegram-bot` api. I do not want everyone to be able to ban members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found after searching a bit. The admin status is stored under `Telegram.ChatMember.status`. It is documented [here](http://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chat.html#telegram.Chat.get_member). It is used by `bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)`. And then getting status in it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `getChatMember` method. See following instance:

[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: What variable is admin stored under?

Comment: @KidDoesCodingAndHasNoFriends its the `status` variable. Check if it is `"creator"` or  `"administrator"`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, but require an additional call to the API. An efficient solution is to cache the list of admins.

A good solution for this is described [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#cached-telegram-group-administrator-check), copied below:

---

## Cached Telegram group administrator check

If you want to limit certain bot functions to group administrators, you have to test if a user is an administrator in the group in question. This however requires an extra API request, which is why it can make sense to cache this information for a certain time, especially if your bot is very busy.

This snippet requires [this timeout-based cache decorator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/325905-memoize-decorator-with-timeout/#c1). ([gist mirror](https://gist.github.com/jh0ker/56f5b4fb7d015b1b9e4c74d4a91d4568))

Save the decorator to a new file named `mwt.py` and add this line to your imports:

```
from mwt import MWT
```

Then, add the following decorated function to your script. You can change the timeout as required.

```
@MWT(timeout=60*60)
def get_admin_ids(bot, chat_id):
    """Returns a list of admin IDs for a given chat. Results are cached for 1 hour."""
    return [admin.user.id for admin in bot.get_chat_administrators(chat_id)]
```

You can then use the function like this:

```
if update.message.from_user.id in get_admin_ids(bot, update.message.chat_id):
    # admin only
```

**Note:** Private chats and groups with `all_members_are_administrator` flag, are not covered by this snippet. Make sure you handle them.

Comment: could you explain please, where did u get 'bot' ? Is this bot same that what we import from telegram -> from telegram import Bot ?